# Using lstListbox.Items.Add(oClass) to listbox of another window

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a class called oToevoegen, how can I add oToevoegen to the listbox of my mainwindow?

Comment: Could you please share what you have attempted so far ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for being so unspecific, I am currently linking the mainWindow using:             MainWindow wdwMain = new MainWindow(); Then using             wdwMain.lstFinanceInfo.Items.Add(oToevoegen); to add the class to the listbox, but the listbox in the mainWindow doesn't update, and the class isn't added (I don't have any errors, so I don't see why this doesn't work)

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Do you see binding errors in the Output window in Visual Studio? Can you include in your question the XAML of `MainWindow` and more context around the code creating the object to be added and calling the `Add` method?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please follow [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) link on how to ask a question and get better answers.

Comment: I'll make a new question, It was really late yesterday, sorry!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510936/how-to-add-item-to-listbox-of-a-different-window-wpf

Answer (score 0):

window1 passes value to MainWindow,following code is my simple demo:

oToevoegen Class:

```
public class oToevoegen
    { 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Window1 code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           MainWindow.oc.Add(new oToevoegen { Name = "Name2" });  
        }
    }
```

Window1.xaml

```
 <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="btn1" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

MainWindow code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static ObservableCollection<oToevoegen> oc { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            oc = new ObservableCollection<oToevoegen>();
            this.lstFinanceInfo.ItemsSource = oc;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            oc.Add(new oToevoegen() { Name = "Name1" });

            Window1 w1 = new Window1();
            w1.Show();
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="lstFinanceInfo" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"/>
    </StackPanel>
```